# Turn off compatibility mode using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to turn off compatibility mode

I've tried using the following HTML meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The issue with this is my document is being loaded within an iframe, so by the time it gets to my meta tag the browser has already been establish in compatibility mode and my meta tag becomes ineffective

I am also unable to place the meta tag in the main document containing the iframe

It would be very helpful if someone knew how to accomplish this with JavaScript or knew of any other approach to solve this

Comment: What have you tried with code?

Comment: Can't be done - it is and IE feature that is not accessible from within the JS runtime.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Please write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that can't be done - it is an IE feature that is not accessible from within the JS runtime

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciate your help.  I'll have to find another way to approach this

Comment: Of course.  Thank you for your answer.  I have accepted it.